# Fundamental theorem of calculus for multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let's say I have a multivariable function $f(x,y)$ that is continuous across $0<x<\infty$ and $0<y<\infty$. I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$\int_{a}^{b} dx \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vert_{y=x},$ where $a,b>0$ and are real.   This is probably a silly question, but can I use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to reduce this down noting we are evaluating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ at $y=x$ in the integral? I think you can't since this isn't a derivative with respect to $x$, but actually a derivative.

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: You mean $C^1$ on the domain?